# How to remove space between period and the prior word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
"I like dogs ."
```

I want to make it to this:

```
"I like dogs."
```

How can I do this using regex? I tried to do the following but it didn't work:

```
  var str = " I like dogs . ";
  str = str.replace(/\s+$/g, "");
```

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: `/\s+(?=\.)/` ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for the easy approach, unless you have some odd layout elsewhere.

```js
str = "I like dogs .";
str = str.replace(/ \./g, '.');
console.log(str);
//output: I like dogs.
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to make it so complicated.

```
> "I like dogs .".replace(/\s+\./, ".");
"I like dogs."
```